# Simplifying a square root

Tags: calculus

How could I simplify the following equation (C1) to become the next equation (C2) knowing that $r \gg d$ ($d$ is significantly smaller than $r$)

$$\begin{align*}
C_1 &= \frac{\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}{d + r - \sqrt{r^2+d^2}}\\
C_2 &= \frac{\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}{d}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{r^2+d^2}=r+\frac{d^2}{2r}+\cdots$

Comment: How do you get to that sequence?

Comment: @JFB:  It comes from the Taylor series for the square root.$\sqrt{r^2+d^2}=r\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}{r^2}}\approx r(1+\frac{d^2}{2r^2})$.  The general case is $(1+x)^n \approx 1+nx$ for $x \ll 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

$$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^n&=&1+nx+\cdots
\\


\implies \sqrt{r^2+d^2}&=&\left(r+\frac{d^2}{r}\right)^{1/2}
\\
&\approx& r + \frac{d^2}{2r}+\cdots

\approx r 

\end{align*}$$

Comment: To add: you already said $d$ is tiny relative to $r$; thus, $d^2$, $d^3$, and higher powers are even tinier, and dividing by (powers of) $r$ makes them tinier than they already are.

Answer (score 2):

Although you say 'simplify,' it isn't actually an equality that you're looking for, But if r is way bigger than d, than $\sqrt{r^2 + d^2} \approx \sqrt{r^2}$.

Can you finish it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $r \gg d$, then $\sqrt{r^2+d^2} \approx \sqrt{r^2}$. You can probably take it from here.